How to hide an intent on a specific platform?
I'm working on Apple Shortcuts implementation in my app. The app works on macOS and iOS. However, I can't support one of the intents on the iOS app.
Hiding it in the new AppIntents API would be simple, but this app still uses the old "intentdefinition" file and I can't migrate it yet.
